# How to create admin route using react router v 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello i'm new to react development and recently react router has been updated to v 6 and that caused a lot of problem when i try to create an admin route. for example in v5 i used .
<AdminRoute exact path={`${path}/makeAdmin`}>


but it does not work in v6. please help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` component API and general routing changed significantly from version 5 to 6. Gone are custom route components, replaced by wrapper components that handle the business logic and return either the `children` prop or an `Outlet` (*for nested `Route` components*), or a redirect (*in the form of a `Navigate` with `replace` prop*).

Example v5 custom `Route`:

```
const AdminRoute = props => {
  const isAdmin = /* admin business logic */;
  return isAdmin ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
};
```

...

```
<AdminRoute exact path={`${path}/makeAdmin`}>
  <ProtectedAdminComponent />
</AdminRoute>
```

Example conversion to v6 using wrapper component:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AdminWrapper =() => {
  const isAdmin = /* admin business logic */;
  return isAdmin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Route element={<AdminWrapper />}>
  <Route path={`${path}/makeAdmin`} element={<ProtectedAdminComponent />} />
</Route>
```